# Tivoli Maximo parameter values from Birt

Tags: parameters, report, birt, maximo

I've been doing reports in Birt, I created a report where I enterer a parameter called service, It is a combobox with many static values(A,B,C,D,E) when you select a value in the comboxbox it loads the report depending on what value you chose from the combobox because this parameter is in the WHERE clause(service= + params["service"]). It works right in Birt, when I run the reports it asks me to select the service value for the report

The problem is when I uploaded it to MAXIMO v7. it does not load the service values I put in Birt. Does anyone had this issue? I've read maximo doesn't have a combobox. Any solutions or recommendations? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the values to an ALNDOMAIN. You should be able to then add a report lookup with the attributename service and kookup name of valuelist.
You can add the new domain via system config, Platform config, domains

Comment: is this possible with a parameter that is NOT bound with attributes? If so can someone point me to details?